# PHP Memory Limit for Toran Proxy

Tags: php, memory, memory-leaks, composer-php, toran-proxy

Im setting up toran proxy to use with our private packages. Im mostly there and testing.

I have Toran Proxy set up on a basic lamp stack on digital ocean and its is configured correctly (from what i know). But when running composer install (on my local dev set up, OSX default apache etc) its saying the package I am requesting isn't available due to a 500 Internal Server error.

```
Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://url.com/repo/packagist/p/lewis/bettercms.json" file could
not be downloaded (HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error)
```

So I checked the apache logs on the server and the fatal error is due to the memory being exhausted.

I have upped it to 2G in the php.ini and restarted apache but still no luck!

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /var/www/toran.lewisecommerce.net/src/Toran/ProxyBundle/Service/Proxy.php on line 470
```

Does anyone have any experienced with setting Toran up? Have you come across any memory issues?

Ive checked php -i and grepped for memory limit which it seems to have picked up the change so im pretty sure php knows this. And I believe I have changed the correct .ini file according to phpinfo() and of course restarted apache. Still no luck.

here is a screenshot of top when under load:
[image: top]

Thanks

Comment: What setting did you change on the `php.ini` ?

Comment: Tha ks for the reply. I have changed memory_limit

Comment: Are you using a virtual server or shared hosting ?

Comment: It's a virtual server that has 2GB memory on digital ocean

Comment: You've found your problem. You vps is lacking memory because other service also use memory, run `top` on your shell to check the available memory.

Comment: But why would toran proxy be using so much memory do you think? Seems very high! I'll check top out again in the morning but when I checked earlier when the server was at 1GB it still had about 400M free memory at the Peak of the operation

Comment: It's difficult for me to tell you what's causing the me4moty issue. Try emailing toran@nelm.io and explain your problem. https://toranproxy.com/support

Comment: `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted` That looks like a very big number, but in reality only is 128MB. If you think you changed the memory limit, PHP seems to not know about it.

Comment: Thanks Sven - Ive checked php -i and grepped for memory limit which it seems to have picked up. And I believe I have changed the correct .ini file according to phpinfo() and of course restarted apache. Still no luck

Comment: The command to identify which INI file is used on the command line is `php -i | grep ini` - this should show you basically any output dealing with ini files and more.

Answer (score 0):

> It's a virtual server that has 2GB memory on digital ocean

You vps is lacking memory because other service also use memory (mysql, mail, etc.), run `top` on your shell to check the available memory.

[image]

---

> But why would toran proxy be using so much memory do you think? Seems
>   very high! I'll check top out again in the morning but when I checked
>   earlier when the server was at 1GB it still had about 400M free memory
>   at the Peak of the operation

It's difficult for me to tell you what's causing the memory issue. Try emailing `toran@nelm.io` and explain your problem. https://toranproxy.com/support

Answer (score 0):

Turns out PHP was using a different .ini file from the one I was changing and believed it to be. Simply changed the PHP value in the correct .ini file.

For Digital ocean this is /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini not the CLI one!